# How to extract data from Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework, can anybody please tell how to extract data from following query and pass the result to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = (from c in db.Customers
                     join b in db.Banks on c.Id equals b.CustomerId
                     join bt in db.BankTransactions on b.Id equals bt.BankId
                     where c.Id == 1
                     orderby bt.Id descending
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = c.Name,
                         Balance = bt.Balance
                     }).Take(1);

        //I want to pass Customer Name and Customer Balance to the view

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: `return View(query.ToList());` ?

Comment: ...and assuming your view accepts `IEnumerable<dynamic>` as model just `return View(query.ToArray());` otherwise do not use an anonymous type...

Comment: You're going to want to call `.ToList()` though, cause, _deferred execution_.

Comment: `.Take(1)` should probably be `.FirstOrDefault()` if you only want to return a single object

Comment: yes..this query should return only single row

Answer (score 2):

Create a view model

```
public class CustomerVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

and modify your query to

```
var query = (from c in db.Customers ...
....
select new CustomerVM
{
  Name = c.Name,
  Balance = bt.Balance
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

then

```
return View(query);
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.CustomerVM
...
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
...
```

Comment: I am not using only one model. There are three models as you can see in the code.
So I cant add @model YourAssembly.CustomerVM in view because its only for one model.

Comment: What? All your code shows is you are combining data from three separate tables into **one** anonymous object. All I'm saying here is rather than using an anonymous object that contains 2 properties, use a view model that contains those 2 properties so you can use it in the view as a strongly typed model and display the properties. You are **not** using three models, you are using data from 3 tables in one model.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't compile this snipet to check, but to solve your problem you could do something like this:

```
        NewObject balanceInfo = query.AsEnumerable().Select(p => new NewObject
        {
            CostumerName = p.Name,
            CostumerBalance = p.Balance
        });
```

I do it a lot when my methods return lists. As I told, I didn't make a query and compiled to test, but I believe that this should solve your problem.